# Difficulty Handling Payment Callbacks and Redirects in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, request, flask-sqlalchemy, payment

I'm currently working on a Flask web application that includes a payment processing feature. I've set up a payment checkout endpoint `(/payment/<int:account_id>)` where users can initiate payments. Upon payment initiation, I'm using a third-party payment gateway that returns a form URL for payment processing. This works fine.
also i have callback /payment/callback This callback contains information about the payment status that the payment service sends

```
@routes.route('/payment/callback', methods=['POST'])
def payment_callback_post():
    data = request.json
    external_id = data.get("id")
    state = data.get("status")
    payment = Payment.query.filter_by(pay_id=external_id).first()
    if payment:
        print(payment.merchant)
        payment.merchant = state
        db.session.commit() 
    result = {
        "state": state,
        "id": external_id
    }
    if state != "paid" and state != "successed":
        print("not payed successfully")
        return jsonify(result)
    db.session.commit() 
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post("https://my-site/payment/status", json=data, headers=headers)
    print("result is", result)
    return jsonify(result)`
```

After a user completes a payment, the payment service redirects them to the /payment/status route in my application. However, the issue arises because the payment service sends the payment status data via a POST request to a callback route `(/payment/callback)`. As a result, when the user is redirected back to /payment/status, it triggers a GET request instead of the expected POST request to retrieve the payment status data.
Consequently, the GET request to /payment/status always returns a failure response since it doesn't receive the necessary payment status data. This leads to an immediate redirection of the user to the `/fail route`.

```
`@routes.route('/payment/status', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def payment_callback_status():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
    elif request.method == "GET":
        data = request.args.to_dict()
    external_id = data.get("id")
    state = data.get("status")
    try:
        payment = Payment.query.filter_by(pay_id=external_id).first()
        if payment and payment.merchant in ['successed', 'paid']:
            acc = payment.acc_id
            print("acc id hooked", acc)
        else:
            print('acc wasnt hook')
            return redirect(url_for('routes.fail'))
    except Exception as err:
        print("Oops:", err)
        return jsonify({"error": str(err)}), 400
    session['account_id'] = acc
    return redirect(url_for('routes.success'))`
```

In the `/payment/status` endpoint of my Flask application, I attempted to handle both GET and POST requests using if conditions. However, despite my efforts, the endpoint consistently responded to GET requests, even when I sent POST requests. This resulted in the inability to properly process payment status data sent via POST requests, leading to unexpected behavior in the application.

Comment: Hello, I didn't understand well your situation, once that the first POST call is done, who call the second GET API? If this is dove via some kinf of UI or other application, you need just fix the code there to make as GET the second call.